# List news webpart required

Tags: web-part, web-part-gallery

I want to be able to display multiple stories from a list on my home page, like a gallery. Eash story will have a graphic assoicated with it. the layout would be like a table 4 x 2 or something similiar. 
The stories should could come from a number of different list in sharepoint.

Any ideas on a webpart or solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using the standard Content Query Web Part?

Answer (score 1):

this could be achieved in several ways depending on how you prefer to work. It could be done using SP UI, creating a view of the news list and displaying the news items as you require them.

Alternatively you could develop a web-part which reads the news list and displays the content in a simple repeater or even utilise some JQUERY to animate the content, a little bit like the image below.

[image]

There is also the excellent RSS Feed Web Part for Office 365 from Rene Modery which can be found here.

[RSS Feed Web Part for Office 365](http://modery.net/updated-release-rss-feed-web-part-for-office-365/)

Hope this helps.

S

Comment: Hi Thanks for the above. I already have someting like that but now need a gallery so all stories have equal importance. Each story might come from different lists. As a thought, could create aspx page as you suggested with jquery using Iframe to add to home page?

Comment: Yes you could create your own aspx page and display using the IFRAME method but if you are referencing SP lists then a web part would be better i think.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an aspx page with Iframe. Seems to work well but not portable!